# Проброс портов через SSH

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, portforwarding

Нужно пробросить порт на сервер.
По ТЗ, у меня UDP соединение, но на сервере не установлен и нет возможности установить netcat(nc). Есть ли возможность пробросить порт для UDP соединения без использования netcat’а

Comment: [yandex://ssh+forward+udp](https://superuser.com/q/53103/454489)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на сервере нет возможности установить netcat

Comment: по ссылке упомянуты и другие варианты. // p.s. а программу можно и скопировать

Comment: @alexanderbarakin посмотрим, а насчет программы, я даже не додумался, попробую, спасибо